# How to activate / deactivate multiple users in asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to give website admin ability to activate /deactivate or unlock multiple users by selecting users and clicking a button .

asp.net membership doesn't have such method ( as far as I know ) . I don't want to call UpdateUser() one time for each user .

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you will have to create a custom stored procedure to which you send a list of user names in a comma separated format and process them on the server. This will be slightly complex and ugly work because you will have to send Application name as well. For each user that your procedure processes call `aspnet_Membership_UnlockUser` SP passing it apllication name (@ApplicationName) and user name (@UserName).

Have a look at the logic of `aspnet_Membership_UnlockUser` SP. Probably you can come up with a better solution.

EDIT: Another solution would be to create a type through .NET assembly that works like a table with a list of usernames that you pass as UDF parameter to SqlCommand. On the server you would use this parameter to either join it with Jigar's query or loop for each item in your type. That could be a better solution because you would be able to reuse the assembly for other such scenarios.

Comment: I have the same idea , I'm trying to find a better way because as you mentioned this solution is ugly and isn't bug-proof

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following logic, however better you use the able way but the logic inside the stored procedure mentioned above is following.

```
UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Membership  
SET IsLockedOut = 0,  
    FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0,  
    FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = CONVERT(datetime, '17540101', 112),
    FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0,  
    FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = CONVERT(datetime, '17540101', 112),
    LastLockoutDate = CONVERT(datetime, '17540101', 112 )  
WHERE @UserId IN (YOUR COLLECTED USERID"S WITH COMMA)
```

Now you need to build logic that call the above SP logic and by this you can get things done.

Comment: thanx , one thing I'm worried aboute . using membership.GetAllUsers() returns userId as well as other information so I can use it but I have to save it somewhere ( gridview DataKey maybe ) . I'm not sure this is safe to have userIds in viewstate ? is there any security issue with UserIds ?

Comment: Well in that case you show user name on the UI and then get the user id retried within the SP. I hope you are getting what I am trying to explain.

Comment: The code that Jigar posted is one of the solutions, but you will have to execute the above code using sp_executesql stored procedure. You will not be able to send a comma separated list of users and pass it directly into SELECT statement because IN part will not work out as correct unless executed through this SP. However, despite the fact that this is a quick solution to the problem I would try to avoid using sp_executesql for a number of reasons.

Comment: well , I'm using the same technique to delete a batch of records by sending a list of ID's separated by comma . without using sp_executesql .